# Microsoft access to Sql Server Data Migration

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, import, ssma

I need to migrate some old MS Access data to a SQL Server Database. Which tool is easier for a newbie to work with: SQL Server Import/Export or Migration assistant for access(SSMA)

Comment: What's your criteria for "better"?

Comment: easier for a  newbie...

Answer (score 1):

I would use the SQL Server import wizard, but make sure to use staging tables to import the data from Access, so you can perform data cleansing before inserting on the definitive tables.

A staging table is a temporary table used to load the data "as is" in the destination system (SQL Server in your case) so you can make sure the datatypes, collation, any custom format is according to your needs. This is made to avoid key/constraint violations, errors due to incompatible datypes, etc...

So for this example, you can import your access tables and ask the wizard to create the new tables during the import, after your are ok with your data, you can insert them in your definitive tables.

Comment: Can you explain a bit regarding the staging process..thanks

Comment: I have expanded my answer trying to explain the staging table concept a little bit more.

Comment: Thanks  a lot. So in a nut shell I can import the data to a temporary table once everything matches then I can transfer those to the final table/destination.

Comment: Yes, it will make your life easier if you encounter any error in your data (in my personal experience, mostly with dates and strings)

Comment: The import wizard works good but I have noticed it does not bring the relationships to the sql database...Is there any way I can copy those relationships

Answer (score -1):

Access can hook up directly to SQL Server through what are called linked tables. Then it's a copy/paste.

Comment: how would you copy paste the table structures and data?